# How do I upgrade bxslider?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm currently trying to fix an app that is using bxslider version 4.1.1
The current version is 4.2.5

Should I just follow the install instructions in order to upgrade? (https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4)

Is there stuff I should be *replacing* instead?

If you are curious, this is the issue I'm trying to fix: 
https://github.com/gnv-org/gnv/issues/14

Comment: Just replace `jquery.bxslider.min.js` and `jquery.bxslider.min.css`. If you use the scripts in the vendor folder, you don't need to change them they are the same version as before (i.e. `fitVids` and `easings v1.3`)

Comment: Thanks! This is the info I was looking for. Why don't you write that as an answer and I'll mark the questions as answered. ... In the interim, the solution was to ask stupid questions and get a generous amount of help. It was upgraded by a volunteer that submitted a pull request. :) I love open source!! I love volunteering on this project but sometimes stuff is just out of my area of expertise. 

Thanks!!

Comment: You're very welcome.Well contributing is always a step forward (well sometimes it's eventual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zer00ne pointed out in the comments, the thing to do is...

replace two files:

`jquery.bxslider.min.js`

`jquery.bxslider.min.css`

Comment: Sound advice,  I agree ;)